# Display width of containing DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm setting up a sort of "debugging" page with a number of unique DIVs with different proportional widths (set in percentages).
I'd like each div to contain text that will display the containing div's width in pixels, responding live to resizing of the viewport.

I'm a relative new to jQuery and have found myself able to display an element's width using:

```
$('.show_width').html($(this).width());​​
```

But, I'm clearly doing something wrong because this only works once - not on every unique div. Further, I'd like to add something like `"Width: ___px"` to each div.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use $.each to loop through the elements

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     getWidths();
     $(window).resize(function() {
         getWidths();            
     });

     function getWidths() {
         $('.show_width').each(function() {
           $(this).html("");
           $(this).html($(this).html() + "<br />Width: " + $(this).width() + "px");
        });
     }
  });​
```

Comment: Mentioned he wanted to add the text: $(this).html($(this).html() + "<br />Width: " + $(this).width() + "px");​

Comment: So, I've got this running at http://jsfiddle.net/9trBs/1/ - but clearly I'm not indicating properly where the width display is supposed to be?

Comment: Alright - here I thought I had it, but I need the resize event callback function integrated as called out below, correct? See http://jsfiddle.net/3wcBT/1/ and resize the width of the preview pane; it does not update. (@MikeSmithDev)

Comment: This works great - now what if I don't want to _replace_ the content already in the div.show_width but rather _append_ it?

Comment: comment out this line: $(this).html("");

Comment: @malificent - tried that, and worked, until you resize the viewport and it keeps writing new width figures.

Comment: guess I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve then...how do you want it to appear?

Answer (score 0):

If i get it, use resize event callback function:

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
         $('.show_width').each(function() {
             $(this).html($(this).width()+' * '+$(this).height());​
          }​
    });
```